# PHP: Delete an Element from JSON array based on condition

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have one JSON array. I want to delete an element which has dispatch_quantity=0.

```
[{
"order_no": "ORDER123",
"dispatch_quantity": "500",
"balance_quantity": "500"
}, {
"order_no": "ORDER123",
"dispatch_quantity": "0",
"balance_quantity": "500"}]
```

So after the operation, Output should be   :

```
[{
"order_no": "ORDER123",
"dispatch_quantity": "500",
"balance_quantity": "500",
}]
```

I tried this:

```
foreach ($data as $json_array) { 
  $dispatch_quantity = $json_array['dispatch_quantity']; 
  if ($dispatch_quantity == 0) { 
    unset($json_array[$i]); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried this 
$i=0;
foreach($data as $json_array) {
    $dispatch_quantity = $json_array['dispatch_quantity'];
    if($dispatch_quantity == 0){
       unset($json_array[$i]);
    }$i++;
}

Comment: do you  decode  it  before  you try  it?

Answer (score 2):

```
$json ='[{
  "order_no": "ORDER123",
  "dispatch_quantity": "500",
  "balance_quantity": "500"
}, {
  "order_no": "ORDER123",
  "dispatch_quantity": "0",
  "balance_quantity": "500"
}]';

$orders = json_decode($json);
$filteredOrders = $orders;
foreach ($filteredOrders as $key => $order)
{
    if ($order->dispatch_quantity == 0)
    {
        unset($filteredOrders[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But it is deleting the complete array.If I print using print_r I am getting 
Array
(
)

Comment: Nop, only dispatch_quantity == 0, I tested locally and the result it's as expected.

Comment: If I print $order-> dispatch_quantity, out from the if condition, I am getting output Array. i.e.it is again an array?

Comment: Maybe you need clone the original array to have a complete array and another filtered